# JS: Efficient way to convert Integer to 8 digit binary?

Tags: javascript, binary, numbers, tostring, 8-bit

I know this can be accomplished in different ways, and there are already some example implementations suggested in other answers.

So what I'm asking is what is **the most efficient in terms of computing** way to do it.

Self explanatory:

```
var num = 3;

console.log(num.toString(2));

//Outputs:   "11"

//Desired output:   "00000011";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please note that I specified the 8 digit notation.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
console.log(("00000000"+num.toString(2)).substr(-8));
```

Or as @LcSalazar stated:

```
console.log(("00000000"+num.toString(2)).slice(-8));
```

Comment: I already have. I get outputs that range from 8 to 12 digits.

Comment: It's impossible, `substr(-8)` returns the last 8 digits of the string.

Comment: You're right. I had a parenthesis balancing mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @ferret96 - A note: You might want to consider using `.slice()` instead. IE doesn't work well with `.substr()`

Comment: Or that, I come from a PHP background.